# Django, django-socketio and mongodb backend

Tags: django, mongodb, socket.io, gevent

I have a running [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) application and I would like to add a real time module using web sockets.

I would like to use [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) but it seems that gevent (which is used to serve the site) does not work properly with mongodb ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-non-relational/sY7eeeCeipw)) which is the backend of the Django application.

Does anyone already try to set up django-socketio with mongodb as a backend ?

Dry

Comment: Out of general interest, is it so that you have not had any problems with django-nonrel (are you also using django-mongodb-engine?) with gevent? The google groups link hinted that there might be problems with that combination.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using Tornado/Tornadio2 with Django is much easier than the gevent-based alternatives. If you need help setting that up I'd be happy to share my runserver_socketio.py script.